# Invoke-SqlVulnerabilityAssessmentScan SetParent failed for Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I am in need of some help folks.  We are trying to get our SQL Vulnerability Assessment to be done via batch in PowerShell.  I'm having some issues setting it all up though and am hoping someone can help me out.

I've tried a few different things but end of the day, I am still getting this error:

```
Invoke-SqlVulnerabilityAssessmentScan : SetParent failed for Database '[master]'. 
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-SqlVulnerabilityAssessmentScan -Credential $cred -ServerInstan ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-SqlVulnerabilityAssessmentScan], FailedOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.VulnerabilityAssessment.InvokeVulnerabilityAssessmentScan
$cred = Get-Credential
$instance = "server\sqldb"
Invoke-SqlVulnerabilityAssessmentScan -Credential $cred -ServerInstance $srv -DatabaseName "master"
```

I also tried this:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$instance = "server\sqldb"
$srv = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server   -argumentlist $instance  
$db  = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database -argumentlist $srv, "master"
Invoke-SqlVulnerabilityAssessmentScan -Credential $cred -ServerInstance $srv -DatabaseName $db
```

but still gives me the same result.

Any help with this is immensely appreciated!

Comment: Check the error log in the SQL Instance and verify that you didnt get a failed login. Verify that you have the correct servername and instance name. If its the default instance (MSQLServer) no instance name is needed.

Comment: i masked the server name & instance name for generic purposes.  the login is working without issue and that is not the problem